# Why the amount of files affects much deleting speed?

Tags: performance, file, memory-management, delete-file

Recently I have figured out, that the amount of files affects much deleting performance. In my project I produce a large amount of report files(about 1 GB in about 90.000 files) daily. I am deleting old reports twice per week. And I have noticed, that about 4 GB in about 350.000 files takes approximately 5 min to delete. I did an experiment with 10 large files 1 GB each(10 GB total) and they were deleted almost instantly.

Does anybody has deeper knowledge how memory works? I thought, that it almost does not matter how many files I am deleting, but only their size. Why this happening?

I have *windows 10* and *NTFS* filesystem

Comment: What Operating System and what filesystem type are you referring to?

Comment: Please note that `GB` is the correct abbreviation for *gigabyte* https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte whereas `Gb` refers to *gigabits*.

Comment: You could maybe consider having one partition on disk for each day, or one partition for the last 4 days and then when you switch, simply *reformatting* the old partition rather than individually deleting the files.

Comment: @MarkSetchell will it be much faster then deleting the files?

Comment: It will depend on your hardware. It's just a suggestion to maybe try when you have some time - it may not be a good solution for everyone. Maybe try (carefully) on a spare, external drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally OS only wipes information bits *about* file (that is file names, attributes, modification times etc., as well as info *where* actual file data was), but not file *content* (which eventually gets overwritten only when you need more space for other files). So, in contrast to what you're saying, the number of files matters in this context *much more*, than their total size.

Having said this, it's still file-system dependent question. Some FS can perform file deletions significantly quicker than others, especially when wiping whole directories and subtrees.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is there any source, where I can read more about this?

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov Well, anything about file systems and how they work, depending on how much you want to know.